# Tags: "moon" / "earths-moon" / "luna" / "lunar-*" / "moons"

Tags: discussion, status-completed

How should things relating to Earth's moon, "Luna"/"The Moon" be tagged. The usual way of distinguishing between our moon and moons in general is to capitalise the word when referring to Earth's moon. Upper-case is not available for tagging. Also, in speech and braile, where case distinction is also absent, longer phrases are used, which we cannot do with tagging either.

Comment: This has been completed mostly according to Pearson's answer, with the exception that the "luna" tag is now used for the Soviet programme by that name.

Answer (score 4):

[luna](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luna) for Earth's moon.  Synonyms [selenology](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenology), [earths-moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earths-moon), etc.

[moons](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons) for moons in general.  Synonyms [natural-satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-satellites), etc.

[moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon) is ambiguous, is there any way to trigger a note "please use [luna](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luna) or [moons](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons) depending on what you want"?

Comment: This is a great answer. As for the last part of it, if we use [tag:moons] (plural), I think it's suggestive enough it's not [tag:luna]. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would say [the-moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon) should be set for Earth's moon. If we do that, and ban the use of the tag [moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon), then a user will be forced to choose between the two. Give an adequate tagwiki, and the problem should be trivial.

Furthermore, there are a few related changes that should be made:

- [moons](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moons) - This should the the primary, synonym [natural-satellite](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-satellite)
- [satellite](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/satellite)- Synonym with [artificial-satellites]
- [the-moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-moon)- Synonym [luna](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luna)

Comment: Should we instead synonimize [the-moon] with [luna]? It would be more useful that way.

Comment: Luna is a fairly rare way to refer to the moon. If you use the word the in front of The Moon, it means Earth's Moon, in any context I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to follow in Wikipedia's footsteps:

[moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moon) for topics relating to the [Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon)

[natural-satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-satellites) for [all other moons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_satellite)

Comment: While I see your reasoning, Wikipedia has a different audience for moon related search results.  The majority of visitors to Wikipedia likely do not realize that moon is a generic term.  The majority of the visitors here could be expected to name a dozen moons in our solar system.